# How to run Sybase SQL script in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sybase

How to execute Sybase SQL Script in C# using ODBC Command?
I tried to fetch all script data in string but it's not working. I saw solution about SQL server but not for Sybase

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Show your work first and tell people what do you achieve and what error/exception you get. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Could you provide code samples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: here's the information about Sybase connection strings, maybe ODBC cannot establish the connection http://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-adaptive/